# Color lost with cv.warpPerspective function

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to inverse a picture from

[image: birdview]

to a normal

[image: perspektiv]

so I can extract two blue lines and copy it to my original image by using the following code:

```
lane_color = [255, 0, 0] #BGR-color

def object_isolation(img, color):
    color = np.uint8([[color]])
    hsv_color = cv.cvtColor(color, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    
    image_hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    lower_range = np.array([hsv_color[0][0][0]-30,hsv_color[0][0][1]-30,hsv_color[0][0][2]-30], dtype = np.int32)
    upper_range = np.array([hsv_color[0][0][0]+30,hsv_color[0][0][1]+30,hsv_color[0][0][2]+30], dtype = np.int32)
    
    mask = cv.inRange(image_hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
    result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img,mask = mask )
    return result

......


image = object_isolation(normal_perspektiv, lane_color) # image only contains the Blue color
lines = np.nonzero(image) 
nonzero_lane_y = lines[0]
nonzero_lane_x = lines[1]

for i in range(len(nonzero_lane_y)):
    frame[nonzero_lane_y[i]][nonzero_lane_x[i]] = [255, 0, 0] # frame is my original image
```

But you can see in the picture, that the blue line is not continuous like the blue line in bird view. How can I draw a much clearly line?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV and not cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV. Images and colors are in BGR format in OpenCV.

Comment: The blue line in the input is only 1 pixel wide. So, the blue line may be aliased away in your perspective view, since it has perspective that narrows from bottom to top of the image. Perhaps make the blue line thicker in your input. You do not show your cv2.warpPerspective. So, it is unclear whether you are using the best interpolation.

Comment: Get the blue line point coordinates in birds eye view and project them with cv2.perspectiveTransforn, then draw them to the warped image directly as line segments.

Comment: @fmw42
1. I have converted the image to RBG at first. :)
2. Thickness is the key XD, Thx lot!

Comment: @Micka 
Hi, thanks. I just used invert version of perspektive transofrmation. But with thickness >1 everything works. :D
```
def birdview(src, dst):
    M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
    Minv = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(dst, src)
    return M, Minv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question:

i just add thickness to the function `cv.polylines(...., thickness = 2)` and it works very good(@fmw42).

End